# minus Sign before Costant in C# but no diffrence I can see in debugging ? any Hidden Feature?

Tags: c#, object

I am just review someone else's code. I got seen this

```
-Globals.TEST_VALUE
```

This have - (minus) before the constant variable. I have debug it but it's have same value as it is.

I thing constant can't be changed. -- Make one value minus from the object. What is use of - here.

Can someone tell me if this have any sense or I just missing something.

Comment: That should give a compiler error. What is the real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is valid.  Take this for instance:

```
Int32 value = -Globals.TEST_VALUE;
```

If `Globals.TEST_VALUE` is a constant `10`, then value will equal `-10`.  `Globals.TEST_VALUE` has not changed, but the assignment to value was made negative of the constant.

Comment: Shit, I forget to see - when I see the result made through Debugging !

Answer (score 2):

It's the expression that consists of a unary `-` operator and a `Globals.TEST_VALUE` constant. It returns the value of `Globals.TEST_VALUE` with inverted sign and doesn't change its value.

If you don't assign or pass it anywhere - it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: `If you don't assign or pass it anywhere - it doesn't change anything` Actually, it changes (i.e.: makes code not-compilable because in c# statements can only be: assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions).

Comment: @PLB: yep, checked it and fixed.